# Asymmetric decryption fails over tcp connection seemingly because of encoding issues

Tags: c#, encoding, public-key-encryption

I am trying to exchange public keys over a tcp connection. It is easier for me if I can do this while storing these keys in a packet class, serializing the packet object, converting it to a byte array and then sending it over the tcp connection.

The problem I run into is that MOST of the time the decryption fails when a encrypted message is returned via this method. I can't be sure why this is but from what I understand using the Encoding.Unicode library can introduce corruption if you're sending keys. What I am looking for is a way for me to send these keys (preferrably as in a JSON format) over a tcp connection without them being corrupted.

I've also read that Convert.FromBase64String() is a source for corruption free encoding but it doesn't seem to always be able to convert JSON strings as they aren't of the correct formatting.

```
//Sets up a tcp conncetion and encrypts a packet
void EncryptAndSend()
{
    //Recieve a string with the public key of the other side with this packet method except I don't encrypt that packet
    //The key is in the format given by rsa.ToXmlString
    string pub_key = "public_key_xml_format";

    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsa.FromXmlString(pub_key);
    string plaintext = "Some plaintext";
    string password = "pass";
    Packet packet = new Packet(PacketType.ENCRYPTED_MESSAGE, plaintext, 0, 1);

    string encrypted_plain = SymmetricEncrypt(plaintext, password);
    packet.payload = encrypted_plain;

    packet.password = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password), false));

    string serialized_packet = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(packet);
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(serialized_packet);

    var client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 5300);
    client.GetStream().Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

//Sets up a tcp connection and decrypts a packet
void RecieveAndDecrypt()
{
    var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 5300);
    listener.Start();
    TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

    var stream = client.GetStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

    while (client.Connected)
    {
        try
        {
            Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            Decrypt(buffer);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected");
        }
    }
}

//Decrypts and prints the packet payload
void Decrypt(byte[] buffer)
{
    string pub_key = "lol";
    string strbuf = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer);
    Packet packet = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Packet>(strbuf);
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsa.FromXmlString(pub_key);
    byte[] decrypt_pass = rsa.Decrypt(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(packet.password), false);
    string decrypted_payload = SymmetricDecrypt(packet.payload, Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decrypt_pass));
    Console.WriteLine(decrypted_payload);
}
```

I run the encryptor in one thread and the decryptor in another. Before these are run I send over the public key from the decryption side in the form of an xml string. I left out this code because I figured my mockup was already long enough and I don't want to overwhelm anyone. If you want the original project source code then I'll gladly dump it.

I forgot to add: I've done a console print right before I decrypt and encrypt the packet to look at what the public and private keys are for encrypting and decrypting a certain packet. As far as I could see the prints are identical, but it seems possible that some bit would be different because of encoding and I don't see it.

The exception that is thrown when I attempt to decrypt is: The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: I do not know if encoding has anything to do with issue.  Encryption requires that exact same number of character that was produced from the encryption method to be used to decrypt.  So when encryption fails first test is to make sure you received the correct number of characters which I believe is the issue.  I would send a byte count at beginning of message and then read the number of bytes before decrypting.  using the wrong encryption method will change byte count and will always fail (except if you are loosing last padding character).

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for replying! I have now tested to see the length of the password after encryption and before decryption. Both times it's 64 (which seems to make sense since a character in a string is 2 bytes). I also tested so that no information was lost in the length of xml public key string. Both on export and import the length was the same. I forgot to add what exception is thrown when decrypting. I will add that to the OP.

Comment: Your encoding is wrong.  You are encoding the password before encryption.  You the send the encrypted bytes.  Next you use encoding to get bytes from the encrypted data before decrypting.  You should do the encoding after the bytes are decrypted.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand exactly what you mean. First I encode my password from a string to a byte array, then I encrypt it and then I encode the encrypted byte array to a string. I then serialize this string into a JSON string. I then encode this string into a byte array and send it over a tcp connection. I then encode this into a JSON string again. I deserialize the JSON string and encode the encrypted string into a byte array I then decrypt this byte array and then encode it into a string again.
Which part do you think I should change? Sorry if it's an obvious answer.

Comment: When you encrypt the decrypt steps must be symmetrical.  The decrypt steps must be in the reverse order from the encrypt methods.  Do not encode the encrypted data.  You will corrupt the data.  For html (jason) use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode("string")  and System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("string")

Comment: S->B->E->B->S->J->B->J->S->B->D->B->S where S is string, B is byte array, E is the encryption, J is the JSON serialization and deserialization and D is the decryption. This seems to be the order of different transformations I do. This seems symmetrical to me. So you're saying that I should not be encoding or decoding in the steps between Encryption and decryption, so I'm guessing the preffered state is always byte arrays then. I will try to implement this, thank you. I'll also use the library you recommended for the JSON transformation.